# Grub menu suddenly showing up even if disabled

Tags: boot, grub2, xubuntu, startup

I have a SBC unit powered by Xubuntu 18.04, being it the single OS in the disk. I have intentionally hidden the grub menu, configuring it like this:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0 

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet loglevel=0" 

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="console=tty12" #Don't show kernel text 

GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="hidden"
```

This works fine except some cases when the menu is showing up again (especially after abrupt system shutdowns). When displayed, the menu has a 30 second countdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grub uses a `recordfail`-variable to change the timeout for the next boot after a boot failure. You can set this variable in `/etc/default/grub`, just add the line

```
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=0
```

to the file and run `sudo update-grub`

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2 in the section `Last Boot Failed or Boot into Recovery Mode`

Comment: Changing the variable didn't work for me, but I have to edit the header script as it is told in the Ubuntu help. Thanks!